# Convert string with AM/PM to 24 hours date format

Tags: r, lubridate, posixct

I have been trying to convert a string with times in AM/PM format to 24 hour date object. 'strtime` coverts to 24 hour format, by keeps adding today's date on the output. The problem is that I need ONLY TIME, such as '13:00'.
Thank you very much in advance!

```
am_pm <- c("8:00 am","3:30 PM",  "10:00 AM", "8:00 AM",  "9:00 PM",  "9:00 
AM")
strptime(am_pm, "%I:%M %p")


[1] "2017-10-19 08:00:00 UTC" "2017-10-19 15:30:00 UTC" "2017-10-19 10:00:00 
UTC" "2017-10-19 08:00:00 UTC"
[5] "2017-10-19 21:00:00 UTC" "2017-10-19 09:00:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Wrap your function in `format(..., format=“%H:%M”)`

Comment: @brittenb is right, but don't use the `“”` smart quotes as R will error out, just use `format="%H:%M"`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an extra step for that. Use `as.ITime()` function from the [lubridate](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.7.4) package.

```
am_pm <- c("8:00 am","3:30 PM",  "10:00 AM", "8:00 AM",  "9:00 PM",  "9:00 AM")
mytime <- strptime(am_pm, "%I:%M %p")

as.ITime(mytime)
```

"08:00:00" "15:30:00" "10:00:00" "08:00:00" "21:00:00" "09:00:00"
[from the docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.7.4)